# How to write HTTP request content to file Asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, http

I am passing some data in HTTP body using the Ajax request. These contents on server are accessible using Request.InputStream. Now i want to write it to file on server disk Asynchronously. How to do that ?

If the data sent using the HTTP is more then i don't want server application to die/get affected. So that i would like to write it Asynchronously.

Following is sample for reference regarding what i am trying to do ...

```
System.IO.Stream str; 
// Create a Stream object.
str = Request.InputStream;
// TO DO Write it to file asyncronously ...
str.Write(someFile, 0, strLen);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream.BeginWrite & Stream.EndWrite are the things to look at.  [Try this MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719596%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be, assuming you're happy to not have control over reading the stream (i.e. you trust that something else will, or happy with it not happening, or not happening in full, is to use a 'virtual stream'.

If you create a class that 'wraps' the stream you wish to use and passes all calls to that underlying stream, you could hook your own logic in the read method, so that when your stream's read method is called you read from the underlying stream, write to your own stream, and then pass it back.

This is not 100% asynchronous as the reader of the stream waits until you write the buffer to your file before receiving the buffer, but it doesn't force the reader to wait until you've read the entire stream and also works well with non-seekable streams.

I wrote a BizTalk-related [whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=bb88dafd-9bba-4d6b-b276-cd7e205f8896) on this with full source code, if you're happy to ignore the BizTalk bits the stream implementation is discussed there in detail

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to do while the file is being written? Something tells me you're mistaken, all proper HTTP servers are multithreaded, so no matter how long a request runs, other requests can be serviced in parallel, too.